# FluentNHibernate-Defining a bag as an Element using Automapping

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate

I have a class that has an `IList` of an enum type. Something like this :

```
public class Enitity
{

       public IList<Usages> Usages{get;set;} //Usages is an enum type

}
```

To define this relation I have implemented `IHasManyConvention` and `IHasManyConventionAcceptance` like this :

```
public class HasManyEnumTypeConvention:IHasManyConvention,IHasManyConventionAcceptance
{
public void Apply(IOneToManyCollectionInstance instance)
        {
            instance.Element.Type(instance.ChildType);
        }
}

public void Accept(IAcceptanceCriteria<IOneToManyCollectionInspector> criteria)
        {
            criteria.Expect(instance => instance.ChildType != null && instance.ChildType.IsEnum);
        }
```

When I try to build a Configuration object using this convention I get an exception as follow :

> The element 'bag' in namespace 'urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2' has
>   invalid child element 'one-to-many' in namespace
>   'urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2'

That I suspect that `FluentNhibernate` is adding both `one-to-many` and `element` elements to a bag.
Obviously I am doing something wrong but I couldn't find any example that uses `automapping` to do the trick.

Please tell me how I can define a bag as an `Element` using `FluentNhibernate Automapping` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I figured it out :) 
You should use an `IAutomappingOverride` implementation to define a bag as an `element` instead of `one-to-many`. Here's how I did it :

```
public class EntityOverride:IAutoMappingOverride<Entity>
    {
        public void Override(AutoMapping<RealEstateFile> mapping)
        {
            mapping.HasMany(x => x.Usage).Element("Usages").AsBag();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is there any way to automap handle this without need to write custom overrides?

Comment: @HomayounBehzadian As you can see this is a very old question thus I don't know if there is a way to that.